# Consulta SQL dos fila de una tabla en un sistema de pujas

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

quisiera saber como podría agregar a una consulta, que ésta también consulte datos de otra fila de la misma tabla, tengo la TABLA "USUARIOS" con filas ID, USUARIO, WEB

```
<?php

$resusuario=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE usuario = 
'".$fs['usuario']."' limit 1");
$fsu=mysql_fetch_array($resusuario);
$email_id  = $fsu['email'];
$email = md5(strtolower(trim($email_id)));
$gravurl = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/$email?d=&s=30";

<div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-0"  style="padding: 10px;">
    <img src="<?=$gravurl?>"  border="0" alt="">
    <a href="#" title="<?php echo 
    $fs['usuario'];?>"><?php echo $fs['usuario'];?></a>

    </div>
```

Lo que deseo es que al hacer click sobre el nombre de usuario lleve a la dirección WEB que tiene asignado en la tabla.
De antemano muchas gracias por la colaboración.

Comment: No está muy claro lo que pides, pero me parece que te interesa mirar como hacer un JOIN con la misma tabla (no tiene ningún secreto, es exactamente igual que entre tablas distintas).

Comment: Gracias por responder, voy a explayar la pregunta.

Comment: Tengo la tabla USUARIO http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9870414tabla-usuario.png

El código lo pueden ver acá exactamente en la línea 201 https://rextester.com/UVD45064 el resultado sería así, http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9870419forma2.png (desde la linea 218-233) dónde dice Tipo de servicio iría el campo WEB de la tabla Usuario

Comment: @Frodo te bastaría con añadir a tu select la condición de que el campo web no esté vacío en el registro o cumpla las condiciones que requieras. Dicho esto, el diseño de una tabla de usuarios suele ser un único registro por usuario para no duplicar información, la información que varíe para un mismo usuario se esperaría que estuviera en otra tabla que se asocia con usuario por el campo id. Por favor, añade las aclaraciones editando la pregunta en lugar de añadir enlaces en un comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría con una vista, o un procedimiento almacenado,
podrías por favor ser mas claro generando el tipo de tabla que tienes y el tipo de resultado que deseas en esta pagina, si no por lo menos hacer un aproximado y ya poder colaborar te.
https://rextester.com/JZTO58225

¿En que motor de BD estas?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `tbl3`$$
USE `EXAPLE_BD`$$

    CREATE VIEW `tbl3` AS
    select id from tbl
    union 
    select texto from tbl;
 DELIMITER ;

select * from tbl3
```

Comment: por favor revisa [answer] pues las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad; añade lo relevante del enlace aquí

Comment: Si lo que pasa es que aun no soy nivel 50 y no puedo dejar comentarios, mi intención es ayudar. Ahí ya me disculpo de antemano por el contenido.

Comment: no hay problema toda la ayuda es bienvenida, como te comento solo añade un ejemplo y verás como la recepción y puntaje de tu prespuesta irá en aumento

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda te mando la tabla Usuario https://rextester.com/NEP69381

Comment: Hola, puedes abstraer un poco más el ejemplo algo como esto:
https://rextester.com/LAAY39587 
Que lo pueda correr y me muestre la tabla con lo que tienes y el resultado que quieres. De igual forma intentaré comprender.

Comment: Cual es la **tabla** con alias _tabla_ que tiene el atributo fecha ? donde esta?

Comment: Si deseas puedo enviarte screenshots del resultado que tengo hasta ahora para que puedas entender que deseo añadir

Comment: Yo creo que la solución va ser creando una vista y ha esa vista hacerle un unión, de la tabla original con la vista que creaste de la tabla original. O la otra es hacer algo como esto
 https://rextester.com/PEVE57173

Comment: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9870414tabla-usuario.png

Comment: Y ahora lo que quieres es hacer una consulta a la misma tabla para traer los datos, voy a dejar un ejemplo de como se hacen las vistas

Comment: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9870415forma.png esto seria el resultado donde están los nombre en azul es el código que te envié en la pregunta, lo que deseo es donde dice Tipo de servicio que la consulta jale los datos de la fila WEB

Comment: A ver si nos aclaramos un poco XD jajaja tu quieres que cuando el usuario le de click a una de esos enlaces se despliegue la pregusta que corresponda, pero entonces el problema ya no sería de SQL si no de programación, bueno entonces lo que tienes que haces es:
1. en las etiquetas en la parte de la ruta manar por método get o POST el ID ese enlace que corresponde a la pregunta.
2.  tomarlo en el archivo php aparte donde vas a mostrar la pregunta y hacer la consulta SQL ahí y mostrarla.

Comment: cual es el primer reto que es relativamente sencillo mandar por método get el ID de ese enlace al archivo PHP y mostrarlo así sea con un echo, luego ya colocar ese id en una variable y haces la sentencia SQL, con el vector que se te genera hacer la vista para el usuario.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bnD1vfapAw

Comment: Lo que deseo es si se puede agregar en la consulta que te mande que también haga el llamado a la fila WEB y obtener este resultado http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9870419forma2.png

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que dices, la url de la pagina web esta en la misma tabla, solo debes poner en le href la url, así como has hecho con usuario

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-0"  style="padding: 10px;">
    <img src="<?=$gravurl?>"  border="0" alt="">
    <a href="<?php echo $fs['urlWeb']; ?>" title="<?php echo 
    $fs['usuario'];?>"><?php echo $fs['usuario'];?></a>

    </div>
```